# override list dictionalry element in FB hydra

Tags: fb-hydra

I have a configuration which I am defining as follows:

**preprocessing**

```
_target_: make_pipeline

steps_config: 
  - ColumnMapper:
      _target_: ColumnMapper
      columns: null
  - SeriesMaker:
      _target_: SeriesMaker
      time_column: null
      value_cols: null
```

Now, I want to specify these null fields from the command line. So, I tried something like:

```
'preprocessing.steps_config.1.value_cols=[x, y]'
```

Now, this comes back with

```
Could not override 'preprocessing.steps_config.1.value_cols'.
To append to your config use +preprocessing.steps_config.1.value_cols=[x,y]
`Key 'value_cols' is not in struct
    full_key: preprocessing.steps_config[1].value_cols
    object_type=dict`
```

I tried various combinations but it does not seem to see the final key in the dictionary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your key seems to be missing an element.
try:

```
'preprocessing.steps_config.1.SeriesMaker.value_cols=[x, y]'
```

Or the equivalent:

```
'preprocessing.steps_config[1].SeriesMaker.value_cols=[x, y]'
```

Comment: One related question: if there was no key in the list emelents, i.e. the "SeriesMaker" was missing and there was only "_target_" and so on, how this override could work?

Comment: You can prefix with + to indicate a new field. see https://hydra.cc/docs/tutorials/basic/your_first_app/simple_cli/.

Comment: No, I don’t mean to add a new field. I mean if the list was not a list of fields having other fields but something like: a: [[b: 1, c: 2], [d: 3, e: 4]] how do you change the value of c?

Comment: Not from CLI, but from another yaml file

Comment: Ask a new question.

Comment: Here is the new post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77940195/overriding-list-entry-in-hydra-from-another-yaml