# Overriding list entry in Hydra, from another YAML

Tags: python, fb-hydra

In Hydra config YAML files, I have the following structure in the file `inner.yaml`:

```yaml
key_a:
    - entry_a_1: xxxx
      entry_a_2: xxxxx
    - entry_a_3: xxxx
      entry_a_4: xxxxx
```

What I want is to be able to override the `entry_a_M` from another YAML file, for example at the file `outer.yaml`:

```yaml
defaults:
    - inner_config@outer_inner_config: inner
outter_inner_config:
    entry_a_1: YYYY
```

I have tried with `key_a.0.entry_a_1: WWWW` and other combinations but it doesn't work.

Please note:

- I don't want to override it from the CLI
- If there are keys in each list item, e.g. `- key: [entry_a_1...]` then it can be done, as shown in question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71565452/override-list-dictionalry-element-in-fb-hydra). But it is not my case and it would not work with having that key in the list entry, in my case.

Any answers on that?

Answer (score 0):

This is not supported directly.
Lists are replaced by `OmegaConf.merge()`, which is what Hydra is using to merge the config objects.

My recommendation is to convert your list to a dictionary. This will allow you to override it by the key.
If your code needs to access the values as a list, you can use the built in OmegaConf resolver [oc.dict.values](https://omegaconf.readthedocs.io/en/2.1_branch/custom_resolvers.html#oc-dict-keys-value).

From the docs:

```py
>>> cfg = OmegaConf.create(
...     {
...         "workers": {
...             "node3": "10.0.0.2",
...             "node7": "10.0.0.9",
...         },
...         "ips": "${oc.dict.values: workers}",
...     }
... )
>>> # Values are dynamically fetched through interpolations:
>>> show(cfg.ips)
type: ListConfig, value: ['${workers.node3}', '${workers.node7}']
>>> assert cfg.ips == ["10.0.0.2", "10.0.0.9"]
```

This can be utilized with `instantiate` by placing the source dictionary outside of the object being instantiated, e.g:

```yaml
objects:
  obj1:
    _target_: __main__.Foo
  obj2:
    _target_: __main__.Foo

main:
  _target_: __main__.Main
  objects: "${oc.dict.values: ..objects}"
```

```
import hydra
from hydra.utils import instantiate
from omegaconf import OmegaConf
from typing import List


class Foo:
    def __init__(self):
        pass


class Main:
    objects: List[Foo];

    def __init__(self, objects):
        self.objects = objects

    def __str__(self):
        return f"Main with {len(self.objects)} objects"



@hydra.main(version_base=None, config_path="conf", config_name="cfg")
def main(cfg):
    print(OmegaConf.to_yaml(cfg, resolve=True))
    obj = instantiate(cfg.main)
    print(obj)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

To complete the solution, you can use the pattern described [here](https://hydra.cc/docs/1.2/patterns/select_multiple_configs_from_config_group/) to select multiple configs from the same config group.
Refactoring the objects in the config above into two separate config files and using the defaults list:

**objects/obj1.yaml:**

```yaml
obj1:
  _target_: __main__.Foo
```

**objects/obj2.yaml:**

```yaml
obj2:
  _target_: __main__.Foo
```

**config.yaml:**

```yaml
defaults:
  - _self_
  - objects:
      - obj1
      - obj2
main:
  _target_: __main__.Main
  objects: "${oc.dict.values: ..objects}"
```

Comment: OK, thank you for the answer. Conversion is not an option. If I could/wanted to do the conversion, I knew that it could work.

Comment: You can make the dict look like a list for the purposes of the app via oc.dict.values.

Comment: Not actually, because there is a chain of `_recursive_` instantiations happening, based on list of added (instantiated) objects

Comment: It might still be possible. I updated my answer. If it's not good enough update your question to reflect your problem better.

Comment: OK, it seems like a possible solution. I will try.

Comment: How to have the "objects" in another yaml and use it with the resolver?

Comment: With the Defaults List. Did you go over the basic tutorial?

Comment: https://hydra.cc/docs/tutorials/basic/your_first_app/config_groups/

Comment: Yes, I know the defaults list and I'm using it quite hard and I override things. So, basically you are saying that if I have in the defaults some entry, e.g. `objects`, then I can call on that entry the OmegaConf resolver?

Comment: I am going to guess you want to select multiple objects for your list. Take a look at this page which demonstrates how to select multiple configs from the same config group. Each one can configure an object in your case: https://hydra.cc/docs/patterns/select_multiple_configs_from_config_group/